# How can I make Timeline / Application Thread notify waiting Threads

Tags: multithreading, javafx, timeline

I have a big problem with multithreading...
I developed a little game and I have a Timeline which updates for example Coordinates of every Sprite in my Application... Now I want to use another Thread which listens to my Keyboard and changes some Coordinates from a GameObject... But the Coordinates change way too often (about 6,8 million Times per second, because the Thread is too fast...). Can I make this Thread wait till the Application Thread has updated the Sprite Coordinates?

Is there any other solution for my Problem?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you use a thread to listen for keyboard events? Why not just register an event listener on the scene, for example?

Comment: Sry its an event listener on the Scene but its set a boolean on true or false and the Thread checks whether its true or not... The thread also checks if there is a collision or not and some more things

Comment: I would recommend an [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) for that, instead of a thread. The `handle()` method is invoked each time the scene is rendered, and it's invoked on the FX Application Thread, which is probably what you want. [Extended example here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842)

Comment: Or, come to that, you could just add a listener to the sprite coordinates and just do what you need when they change.... Really it is not at all clear what your thread is doing here.

Comment: I tried an AnimationTimer but the problem was that on my DesktopPC the Sprite moved faster than on my Notebook... If I counted the method calls per second it was double as fast as the Timeline...

Comment: That just sounds like it is not implemented correctly. The `handle()` method receives a time stamp, so you can calculate how far to move the sprite. But if you prefer a timeline, why not just invoke the code you need from the timeline, instead of in a thread. You probably need to create a [MCVE] (please read that link and understand it) as it's really not possible to see what the problem is from your description.

Comment: 6.8 _million_ times per second?  What's the use of updating graphic objects more often than your monitor is able to display them?